# Is Google Sign-In not supported on Firefox?

Tags: html, google-signin

I'm trying to run the default example code (using my Client ID) linked at:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

The code runs correctly on Google Chrome browser (returning all user infos) while it throws an exception using Firefox:

```
"uncaught exception: [object Object]"
```

Can anyone help me?
Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please delete all cookies from google and clear your cache then restart Firefox. If does not work go back into cookies and clear everything that you know you do not need. Also check your Firewall software see if anything adds up to google and can put a exemption in maybe. Also turn off any adblockers when go to the site.

If that does not work https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

Answer (score 2):

In SSL case only; put in HEAD the following meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:; script-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; style-src https: 'unsafe-inline' ">
```

Even though https: is specified in default-src, the script and style directives don't automatically inherit that source. Each directive completely overwrites the default for that specific type of resource.